# Storing Scraped Output into Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I would like to store the scraped information from Instagram into a dataframe. 
Here is the part of the code that works well.

```
pip install igramscraper
from igramscraper.instagram import Instagram
instagram = Instagram ()
ralphlauren = instagram.get_account('ralphlauren')
rlmedias = instagram.get_medias("ralphlauren", 1000)
l=[]
for rlmedia in rlmedias:
    print(rlmedia)
```

Below is the output of the last line:
[image: Image Output]

As i would like to store each information into a different column, I try the following code instead:

```
l=[]
for rlmedia in rlmedias:
    d= {} 
    d['ID'] = get_medias.find("ID:").text
    d['Shortcode'] = get_medias.find("Shortcode:").text
    d['Created at'] = get_medias.find("Created at:").text 
    d['Caption'] = get_medias.find("Caption:").text
    d['Number of comments'] = get_medias.find("Number of comments:").text 
    d['Number of likes'] = get_medias.find("Number of likes").text
    d['Link'] = get_medias.find("Link:").text 
    d['High res image'] = get_medias.find("High res image:")
    d['Media type'] = get_medias.find("Media type:").text
    l.append(d)# adding the item into the dictionary
```

The code above doesn't work because "NameError: name 'get_medias' is not defined".
Could you help me point out how I can store the information from the output into different columns?

[image: rlmedia]

Comment: you want to use instagram.get_medias instead of get_medias

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. However, AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'find' @Mrml91

Comment: my mistake I think you want to use `rlmedia` since you are iterating over these values but I can't help you any further because I don't know the type of these `rlmedia`objects

Comment: Type(rlmedia) returns a "list"

Comment: can you print just one `rlmedia` so that I can see what it's like please ?

Comment: sure! it is in the edited question

Comment: it doesn't look like a list. Are you sure `list` isn't the type of `rlmedias` rather than the one of `rlmedia`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: type(rlmedia) returns a "igramscraper.model.media.Media". type(rlmedias) returns a "list".

Comment: I think you must access every attribute of the `rlmedia` that you need. All attributes can be seen there : https://github.com/realsirjoe/instagram-scraper/blob/master/igramscraper/model/media.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212171/discussion-between-tony-flager-and-mrml91).